# Block diagram reduction with multiple inputs

Tags: dynamical-systems, control-theory

[image: Block diagram]

I need to reduce the diagram, when each input is 0, I can do when d=0, however i'm finding it a little difficult when r=0.

I have solved the exercise using a signal flow diagram and the solution is written here, i'm not getting the same result from block reduction.

[image: solution via signal flow graph]

Answer (score 1):

It might help if you rearrange the block diagram a little, namely the first is represented with

[image]

which after some shifting around it is equivalent to

[image]

It can also be solved by introducing some temporary variables, usually defined after summation nodes and then solve a system of linear equations. This would allow you to simultaneously solve for $C(s)$ as a function of $R(s)$ and $D(s)$.